# RStudio, how to change the width of the variables field?

Tags: rstudio

Is it possible in RStudio to change the width of the field with the names of the variables? I often have variables with long names that are not fully shown. Of course, I could simply make the whole window larger, but then the editor window gets smaller, which I don't want it to.
[image: Annotated screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible

Further informations on the RStudio Support page: [Environment-pane-cutting-off-variable-names](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200865496-Environment-pane-cutting-off-variable-names)

The official comment is:

> Unfortunately this is currently not possible but its something we're looking into implementing going forward. In the meantime, hovering over the variable names in the Environment pane should bring up a tooltip that states the full name of the variable - hopefully that will be helpful to you for this purpose.